# How to change size of a tableview if there is no image to load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I´m doing a View with a TableView and a ImageView. I want to load a image from a URL and change the size of the ImageView component if needed. But in other hand, if there isn´t any image from the URL, I want to hide the ImageView component and makes the TableView component to fills the entire screen.

This is an example:

[image: Screen]

How I can do that?

EDIT:

My code after all, is that, but the Image is not loaded in the UIImageView :S

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[bannerArray objectAtIndex:0] cvp_html]];


                        [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                                            options:0
                                                                           progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize)
                         {
                             // progression tracking code
                         }
                                                                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
                         {
                             if (image && finished)
                             {
                                 NSLog(@"IMG DOWNLOAD COMPLETED");
                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
                                     iv_banner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

                                     NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);

                                     int heightOfTheTopButtons = 50;

                                     if([imgData length] > 0) {
                                         CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, (heightOfTheTopButtons), self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height-(heightOfTheTopButtons)) );
                                         tableview.frame = newFrame;
                                     }

                                 });
                             }
                         }];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the image data is bigger than 0.

```
UIImage * image = imageFromUrl;
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0); 

if([imgData length] > 0) {
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, (heightOfTheTopButtons), self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height-(heightOfTheTopButtons));
    tableView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have two buttons on top of the tableview, with self.view.frame.size.width and self.view.frame.size.height I could overlap this buttons?

Comment: Oh okay - you could find the height of the top-buttons and then set off that amount in the tableview frame. I'll update the answer now.

Comment: Thanks @simon-degn, I will try to do the async download of the image, and later I will give a try to your code. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds great! Please upvote my answer if you like it :-)

Comment: Simon, I have the next error: ""Initializing 'CGRect *' (aka 'struct CGRect *') with an expression of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')""

Comment: Try to remove the * (star)